# Secondary Index not working for Database using @key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I should get the DynamoDb id for Justin. The call doesn't seem to fail. If i `console.log(returned)` i get an `[object Object]`. When i try to get to the `returned.data.getIdFromUserName.id` or `returned.data.getIdFromUserName.email` (anything else in the table) i get `undefined`. What am i missing?

Returned data:

```
{
  "data": {
    "getIdFromUserName": {
      "items": [
        {
          "id": "3a5a2ks4-f137-41e2-a604-594e0c52a298",
          "userName": "Justin",
          "firstname": "null",
          "weblink": "@JustinTimberlake",
          "email": "iuiubiwewe@hotmail.com",
          "mobileNum": "+0123456789",
          "profilePicURI": "null",
          "listOfVideosSeen": null,
          "userDescription": "I wanna rock your body, please stay",
          "isBlocked": false,
          "GridPairs": null
        }
      ],
      "nextToken": null
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest getting a better idea of what `console.log(returned)` is printing.

Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(returned, null, 2))` to inspect what is being returned.

EDIT:  The data you're working with looks like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "getIdFromUserName": {
      "items": [
        {
          "id": "3a5a2ks4-f137-41e2-a604-594e0c52a298",
          "userName": "Justin",
          "firstname": "null",
          "weblink": "@JustinTimberlake",
          "email": "iuiubiwewe@hotmail.com",
          "mobileNum": "+0123456789",
          "profilePicURI": "null",
          "listOfVideosSeen": null,
          "userDescription": "I wanna rock your body, please stay",
          "isBlocked": false,
          "GridPairs": null
        }
      ],
      "nextToken": null
    }
  }
}
```

Pay close attention to the structure of that response.  Both `data` and `getIdFromUserName` are maps.  The content of `data.getIdFromUserName` is an array named `items`.  Therefore, `data.getIdFromUserName.items` is an array containing the results of your query.  You'll need to iterate over that array to get the data you are looking for.

For example, `data.getIdFromUserName.items[0].id` would be `3a5a2ks4-f137-41e2-a604-594e0c52a298`

Comment: You're right. I AM getting the data packet returned which is a positive. However i don't know how to access the id from it. I've updated the post with what i get back. Please let me know how to access just the id. No combination i'm trying works.

Answer (score 0):

To access the email it would be `data.getIdFromUserName.items[0].email`.